# jmockit verifications block throwing Missing 1 invocation to methodName

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, jmockit

Am trying to run one test case which will update the data into DB. This is my source code of test method.

```
@Tested // This is class-level scope as I have different test methods.
FirstLevelClass firstLevelClass;

@Test
public void testUpdateDB(@Mocked SecondLevelClass secondLevelClass) throws Exception {

        // Updated method by passing an argument.
        firstLevelClass.updateDatabaseThroughSecondLevelClass(info);

        new Verifications() {{
            SecondLevelClass.updateDB(creds, data);
            times =1;
        }};
```

Here my intention is to verify the expected invocations to mocked methods[which recorded in expectations]. But, verifications block is giving the following exception message. If I remove **times=1**, then test case is getting success. That is not my desired result.Can anyone please suggest me what could be wrong in my test case.

**mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing 1 invocation to:**
SecondLevelClass#updateDB(creds, data)
   with arguments: creds, data

**Caused by: Missing invocations**

**Updated Question :**

There is one argument to `updateDatabaseThroughSecondLevelClass(info)`, from that argument we are forming creds reference in SecondLevelClass.

```
Credentials creds = info.getCredentials();
```

But in verifications block[**Which is part of FirstLevelClass**] we have created locally test object.

```
Credentials creds = getCredsTestObject();
```

This is the reason why it complained about `Missing invocations`. Because both are two different references in two classes. Can anyone please suggest me how to handle this case.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Where do `creds` and `data` come from? I guess they are not the same values as actually passed to `updateDB` from `updateDatabaseThroughSecondLevelClass`, so you get the "missing invocation". BTW, recent versions of JMockit don't have a `NonStrictExpectations` class anymore; also, there's no point in *recording* this expectation if it's going to be verified at the end of the test (it's redundant). Also, `@Tested` creates an instance by itself, no need to do it explicitly. Take a few minutes to read the documentation, there are lots of examples.

Comment: Rogerio, please read my updated question and please suggest any way to handle this case.

Comment: The question still lacks essential information: how are `info`, `creds`, and `data` created, before being used in the test? It would also help if code for `FirstLevelClass` was shown.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in the integration between TestNG and JMockit: https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/337

Comment: Hi Juherr, I have used the same concepts for other class, its worked. In this class only am facing problem.

Comment: While debugging when the flow comes to times=1, then its throwing exception. Couldn't find what exactly the reason causing this issue.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with TestNG. Apparently (code under test wasn't shown...), the arguments with which `updateDB` get called simply are not equal to the ones used in expectations.